# Printing to .txt file in java not working

Tags: java, android, text-files

I am wanting to store some variables in a .txt file for storage and have attempted to use the PrintWriter functions, however the txt file i am trying to create doesn't actually create, let alone write to the file!

Code:

```
            if(new String("SimpleBLEBroadcaster").equals(result.getDevice().getName()))
                peripheralTextView.append("Device Name: " + result.getDevice().getName() + " rssi: " + result.getRssi() +" Packet length: " + PacketLength + " Packet Data: " + "0x" + R + "\n");

            File myObj = new File("C:\\Users\\Josh Gascoigne\\Documents\\Uni stuff\\Android Studio\\Data.txt");
            PrintWriter DataOut = null;
            try {
                DataOut = new PrintWriter("Data.txt");
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            DataOut.println(R);
            DataOut.close();
```

I have followed a few tutorials on how best to use the print writer function and copied a youtube tutorial but using my variables and i cant understand why the txt file isnt being created. i even tried generating the file prior to writing to it. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You tagged this as [tag:android-studio], by which I assume you mean [tag:android]. Is this code supposed to run on an Android device (or emulator)? If so: that path you specify obviously doesn't exist on that device/emulator, that's a path on your *local machine* (which an Android app won't be able to access). Check [the docs](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage) for storing data on Android. If this is **not** meant to run on an Android device, then please remove the Android tag.

Comment: You're specifying a full pathname in `myObj`, but then ignoring that entirely and instead just passing in `"Data.txt"` to the `PrintWriter` constructor. That will create the file in the working directory of the process - is that what you expected?

Comment: There is no `C:` folder on an android device. Moreover you could try `DataOut = new PrintWriter(myObj);`

Comment: what error you are getting? There could be permission issue or path issue. Your myObj is pointing to ur computer and PrintWriter  is pointing to android phone.

Comment: @JoachimSauer i am trying to run this on an android app currently. The App successfully prints all relevant data. For testing purposes i want to store all the outputs I receive in a .txt folder on my laptop i am using android studio on. Is this possible?

Comment: @JonSkeet originally the myObj line was not in the code, i was expecting the file to be created in my directory. but it doesnt show up there!

Comment: @GAZZA: no, your app can't write to your computer. The Android app runs on an Android device (even if that device happens to be emulated). If it could write to your computer that would be a serious security risk.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Thanks i will clarify the actual requirements with my colleagues as from my understanding that is what was asked. But clearly not possible

Answer (score 1):

Your constructor for `PrintWriter` should be as follows;

```
DataOut = new PrintWriter(myObj);
```

Refer: [PrintWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter-java.io.File-)

**----------------Explanation-----------------**

What your code is doing is that the `PrintWriter` is not referring to the same file that you are instantiating in the code above.

> File myObj = new File("C:\Users\Josh Gascoigne\Documents\Uni stuff\Android Studio\Data.txt");

What you code is possibly doing is creating a new file `Data.txt` in the working directory of the program.
So basically, you referring to the file `C:\\Users\\Josh Gascoigne\\Documents\\Uni stuff\\Android Studio\\Data.txt` is redundant.

Referring to the variable `myObj` in the `PrintWriter` constructor should fix that redundancy. (Provided that is what your use case is.)

Comment: I see how the myObj and the print writer code contradict each other! i have changed the code following yours and @Nnoama miracle suggestions and still no TXT file is being created in the myObj  directory

Answer (score -1):

There's no such path as `c:\` on any Android device.
Then your print writer too.
You didn't even specify any path.
At least try something like

```
File destination = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "data.txt");
Dataout = new PrintWriter(destination);
Dataout.println(R);
Dataout.close();
```